# Limiting character length of output

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have this:

```
<?php
    $trim_length = 40;
    $custom_field1 = 'slide1_title';
    $custom_field2 = 'slide2_title';
    $custom_field3 = 'slide3_title';

    $value1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field1, true);
    $value2 = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field2, true);
    $value3 = get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_field3, true);
?>
```

At the moment I want to limit words but want to create a function and parse two arguments:

1. custom_field{?}
2. Maximum Characters

I am in a wordpress development, at the moment I am using, this every line:

```
<?php echo rtrim(substr($value1,0,$trim_length)); ?>
```

(currently only 3 times - however this maybe more!)

Can someone provide some direction here, as I would also like to add three bullet points (...) at the end of the count for a help ui for the visitors.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
function shortString($value, $maxLength = 50, $postfix = '...')
{
    if (strlen($value) > $maxLength) {
        $value = mb_strimwidth($value, 0, $maxLength, $postfix, 'UTF-8');
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Comment: can you add to the above how this function would be used?

Comment: <?php echo shortString($value1,$trim_length); ?>

Comment: Just for clarification my code works. However I was looking for a function based answer which would not the variables above. As I would still have to build the custom_field and value variables into the function. Otherwise I would create more code not less. Could this be done? many thanks!